# How to sort NSTableView using Image Cell (image) in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a NSTableView that is bound using Cocoa Bindings. One column of that table is an image cell. Total images I'm using are only 2, so they can be repeated on each row.

**How can I sort my NSTableView, to display first rows that have image1.jpg and, after that, rows that have image2.jpg?**

I can't control it when I'm adding rows to the underlying array because they can be added in random order.

Comment: Are you using Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XIB editor, you can double click the table column and select the "Attributes" pane and set a sort key.

If you're using Core Data, you'd probably have to add something like an "imageName" property to your entity, and set the sort key to `imageName` and the selector to `compare:`

If not, you can just set the sort key to `image.name` and the selector to `compare:` and it should work fine.

That allows the user to select the table column header to sort the image column. If you want sorting to happen automatically you can set the sort descriptor in code, with the same keys I listed above.

Edit: Do you have your XIB set up like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. No I'm not using Core Data. I tried to do as you said, but it won't work. Probably missed something. Can you give example with more details? What you mean image.name? Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly right that. Sort key - Just needs to be Image name? like "image1.jpg" ? I tried but it still doesn't do it.

Comment: Are you sure your image actually has a name? Try setting the image name manually when you initialize it. What model key path is your table column bound to? Mine is bound to "Value" using a value transformer to create an NSImage from the raw data, as the "Data" binding seems to be deprecated.

Comment: I'm new in Cocoa. Column is binded using Cocoa bindings. Here some part of it image=[imageNotFound image];
            }
            
            NSDictionary *dictForEachRow =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                                             image, @"browseImageState"}   What you mean with image name? Something like "image3423.jpg" ?

Comment: Send me an email with a copy of your code so I can see what you're doing.

Comment: Hmm. support@throwbackapp.com